# How do I use sharp icons in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, font-awesome

How do I use alternative icon styles like `fa-sharp fa-solid fa-user` in R Shiny?

https://fontawesome.com/icons/user?s=solid&f=sharp

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("test", "Test", icon = icon("fa-sharp fa-solid fa-user")) # doesn't work
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you try with `actionButton("test", "Test", icon = icon("user", class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-user"))`

Comment: This made my logo solid but not sharp

Comment: It is a pro icon and not free.  Do you have that icon

Comment: There's a similar icon in the `glyphicon` library, this one is available in Shiny <https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_user&stacked=h>